# complex numbers powers with symbolic variables_matlab

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

While I was trying to solve some complex numbers related equations I came up with the following problem:

When I try to extract the real and imaginary part of a complex number raised in a symbolic variable power I get no result. On the other hand if I transform it to its trigonometric form I get the proper result. To clarify this I quote the following examples:

```
syms n real;
Re1 = real(i^n)
Re1 =
real(i^n)
Re2 = real(exp(i*n*pi/2))
Re2 =
cos((pi*n)/2)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to perform such kind of calculations without initially transforming the complex number to its trigonometric form.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/real.html) states "In general, real cannot extract the entire real parts from symbolic expressions containing variables.", so I guess there is not much you can do

Comment: you are probably right. thank you for your comment ; )